# turtle_tf2_broadcaster,turtle_tf2_listener,c++

Tags: ros-melodic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone:

I am practising these two web pages:

http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20broadcaster%20%28C%2B%2B%29

and:

http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf2%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29

I met two questions as follows:

If everything went well, you should have a binary file called turtle_tf2_broadcaster in your bin folder. If so......

and

If everything went well, you should have a binary file called turtle_tf2_listener in your bin folder. If so......

What and where is this bin folder?
Also I don't find these two files anywhere:a binary file called turtle_tf2_broadcaster,a binary file called turtle_tf2_listener.

Who can give me a hand? Thank you for your kindness and patience.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350915/turtle_tf2_broadcaster,turtle_tf2_listener,c++/) by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) on ROS Answers with karma: 17 on 2020-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I deleted sth and did again,and it works.
This question is closed.

---

Originally posted by [Dean](https://answers.ros.org/users/53030/dean/) with karma: 17 on 2020-05-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0